# parse a string by delimiter and sum

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to be able to parse out a string, then group by and sum by a specific parts of the string. The issue is the value I need to sum is not in the same position.

for example something like this. 9 strings:

```
1111^Blue^220UU^2^AAAAA^BBBBB^CCCCC

1112^Blue^220UU^3^AAAAA^BBBBB^CCCCC

1113^Blue^220UU^2^AAAAA^BBBBB^CCCCC

1114^Red^220UU^AAAAA^BBBBB^1^CCCCC

1115^Red^220UU^AAAAA^BBBBB^1^CCCCC

1116^Red^220UU^AAAAA^BBBBB^2^CCCCC

1117^Green^220UU^AAAAA^2^BBBBB^CCCCC

1118^Green^220UU^AAAAA^3^BBBBB^CCCCC

1119^Green^220UU^AAAAA^3^BBBBB^CCCCC
```

the delimiter here is ^. I'd like to group by the first position between the ^ (Blue,Red,Green) and sum the quantities which are in different positions depending on the color.

for Blue its position 3, for Red its position 5, and for Green its position 4

this is the desired result

```
COLOR   QTY
Blue    7
Red 4
Green   8
```

in this example the 220UU is the only thing they all have in common. the AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC is just other random data I cannot match or group with.

hope Im explaining this enough. I am still newish to sql and this is the most complex thing I have tried to do so far

I have tried this, attempting to use a case statement for each of the colors and then sum by the specific position of that colors qty. when I run this I am geting "invalid number" error

```
select nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,1), instr(t.data,'^',1,2)-instr(t.data,'^',1,1)-1)),'') COLOR,
case 
    when nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,1), instr(t.data,'^',1,2)-instr(t.data,'^',1,1)-1)),'') = 'Blue'
        then sum(nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,3), instr(t.data,'^',1,4)-instr(t.data,'^',1,3)-1)),''))
    when nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,1), instr(t.data,'^',1,2)-instr(t.data,'^',1,1)-1)),'') = 'Red'
        then sum(nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,5), instr(t.data,'^',1,6)-instr(t.data,'^',1,5)-1)),''))
    when nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,1), instr(t.data,'^',1,2)-instr(t.data,'^',1,1)-1)),'') = 'Green'
        then sum(nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,4), instr(t.data,'^',1,5)-instr(t.data,'^',1,4)-1)),''))
end as QTY
from table t
where t.data like '%^220UU^%'
group by nvl(to_char(substr(t.data, 1+instr(t.data,'^',1,1), instr(t.data,'^',1,2)-instr(t.data,'^',1,1)-1)),'');
```

Comment: One such example: https://www.databasestar.com/sql-split-string/

Comment: Might be able to use https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use SubStr() and InStr() functions to get elements of the string and then Case expression for conditional sum.

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select '1111^Blue^220UU^2^AAAAA^BBBBB^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1112^Blue^220UU^3^AAAAA^BBBBB^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1113^Blue^220UU^2^AAAAA^BBBBB^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1114^Red^220UU^AAAAA^BBBBB^1^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1115^Red^220UU^AAAAA^BBBBB^1^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1116^Red^220UU^AAAAA^BBBBB^2^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1117^Green^220UU^AAAAA^2^BBBBB^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1118^Green^220UU^AAAAA^3^BBBBB^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual Union All
          Select '1119^Green^220UU^AAAAA^3^BBBBB^CCCCC' "TXT" From Dual 
        ),
```

... cte - extracting elements from delimited string

```sql
  elements AS
    ( Select    SubStr( TXT_2,InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 1) + 1, InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 2) - InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 1) - 1 ) "COL_1",
                SubStr( TXT_2,InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 2) + 1, InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 3) - InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 2) - 1 ) "COL_2",
                SubStr( TXT_2,InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 3) + 1, InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 4) - InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 3) - 1 ) "COL_3",
                SubStr( TXT_2,InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 4) + 1, InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 5) - InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 4) - 1 ) "COL_4",
                SubStr( TXT_2,InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 5) + 1, InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 6) - InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 5) - 1 ) "COL_5",
                SubStr( TXT_2,InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 6) + 1, InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 7) - InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 6) - 1 ) "COL_6",
                SubStr( TXT_2,InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 7) + 1, InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 8) - InStr(TXT_2, '^', 1, 7) - 1 ) "COL_7"
      From      ( Select -- delimiter added to start and end of string
                            TXT, '^' || TXT || '^' "TXT_2", 
                         -- number of elements in string
                            Length('^' || TXT || '^') - Length(Replace('^' || TXT || '^', '^')) - 1 "CNT"   
                  From      tbl
                )  
    )
```

... analyze cte elements ResultSet

```sql
/*
COL_1       COL_2       COL_3        COL_4       COL_5      COL_6       COL_7                                 
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1111        Blue        220UU       2           AAAAA       BBBBB       CCCCC                                 
...
1114        Red         220UU       AAAAA       BBBBB       1           CCCCC                                 
...
1117        Green       220UU       AAAAA       2           BBBBB       CCCCC                                 
...                                                                                 */
```

... and use Case expression to Sum the right column depending on color

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select    COL_2 "COLOR", Sum(Case COL_2 When 'Red'    Then COL_6
                                        When 'Blue'   Then COL_4
                                        When 'Green'  Then COL_5 End) "QTY"
From      elements
Group By   COL_2
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t : 
COLOR                 QTY
----------     ----------
Blue                    7
Red                     4
Green                   8 */
```

NOTE: The code above uses Oracle's implicit conversion of char to number (for summing) - check your data for possible non-numeric characters and handle it if needed.

Comment: thank you @d r, this solution was what I was looking for. It worked for my specific problem. thanks to all others who input as well

Answer (score 1):

Your goals may be achieved with the [`regexp_substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) function

```
select
  regexp_substr("data", '[^\^]+', 1, 2) color,
  sum(regexp_substr("data", '[^\^]+', 1,
                    case regexp_substr("data", '[^\^]+', 1, 2)
                      when 'Blue' then 4
                      when 'Red' then 6
                      when 'Green' then 5
                    end)) qty
from "table" t
group by regexp_substr("data", '[^\^]+', 1, 2);
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0RDwcDWi).

Comment: This does not need CASE `sum(REPLACE(regexp_substr("data", '\^[0-9]+\^'), '^','')) qty`

Comment: Nor this `sum(regexp_substr("data", '[0-9]+', 1, 3)) qty`. Does assume there are no other numbers mixed into those alpha substrings.

Comment: @June7, why not :) But that's sql_noobie's question, and that's why he/she sets the rules.